# Kubernetes jobs and back-off limit values: is the value a number of retries or minutes?

Tags: kubernetes, jobs, kubernetes-cronjob

I was [reading the Kubernetes documentation about jobs and retries](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/). I found this:

> There are situations where you want to fail a Job after some amount of
>   retries due to a logical error in configuration etc. To do so, set
>   .spec.backoffLimit to specify the number of retries before considering
>   a Job as failed. The back-off limit is set by default to 6. Failed
>   Pods associated with the Job are recreated by the Job controller with
>   an exponential back-off delay (10s, 20s, 40s …) capped at six minutes.
>   The back-off count is reset if no new failed Pods appear before the
>   Job’s next status check.

I had two questions about the above quote:

1. The back-off limit value is on minutes or number of retries? The documentation example using the value **6 (six)** is confuse, because he initially affirms that the value is the number of retries but after that said "capped at **six** minutes".
2. There is a way to define the back-off delay time? As I understand, this behavior (10s, 20s, 40s …) is default and can't be changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No confusion about the `.spec.backoffLimit` is is the number of retries.

The Job controller recreates the failed Pods (associated with the Job) in an exponential delay  (10s, 20s, 40s, ... , 360s). And of course, this delay time is set by the Job controller.

- If the Pod fails, after 10s new Pod will be created
- If fails again, after 20s new one will be created
- If fails again, after 40s new one comes
- If fails again, next one comes after 80s (1m 20s)
- If fails again, next one comes after 160s (2m 40s)
- If fails again, after 320s (5m 20s), new Pod comes
- If fails again, after 360s (not 640s, cause it is greater than 360s or 6m) you will see the next one

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/eefcf6aa801c5db48b564d0464470d623b8bfb79/pkg/controller/job/job_controller.go#L764-L765), it seems like the `backoffLimit` attribute specifies the failure count rather than failure time.

Excerpt of the code mentioned above:

```golang
func (jm *Controller) syncJob(ctx context.Context, key string) (forget bool, rErr error) {
    // ...

    succeeded, failed := getStatus(&job, pods, uncounted, expectedRmFinalizers)

    // ...

    jobHasNewFailure := failed > job.Status.Failed
    exceedsBackoffLimit := jobHasNewFailure && (active != *job.Spec.Parallelism) &&
        (failed > *job.Spec.BackoffLimit)

    // ...
}
```